# Integration tests for Azure with test data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm doing integration tests with Watin for my MVC4 app and everything works great. I was just wondering, is it possible to start Azure with custom Web.config just for testing?

Right now I have to switch connection settings in Web.Debug.config and remove all data from storage, but it takes a lot of time. Does anybody know for better more automated way?

So goal is to run Azure server with additional Web.config and reset storage.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible way to do this.

One way would be creating two Cloud projects, one for regular development and one for testing. There would be a few steps involved here:

1. Move all your database configuration out of web.config and into the CSCFG file. This is usually a good idea anyway when working in Azure.
2. Create a new Cloud project. Point it to the same site as your existing project.
3. Change the CSCFG in the new project to use your integration test settings.
4. Add a post-build event that calls "dsinit /forcecreate" to rebuild storage

Alternatively, you may be able to do it by create a separate Build Configuration that does what you want. I'm not sure this would work, but it would be something like:

1. Create a Test build configuration (Build -> Configuration Manager -> Active Solution Configuration -> New...)
2. Create a Web.Test.config file with the correct settings
3. Add a conditional post-build event that runs "dsinit /forcecreate" only in the Test configuration.

Comment: I like the second idea but its not picking up Web.Test.config.. I wonder why

Comment: Did you run the build in Test configuration? Also note that you have to Publish the website, or else it won't apply the transformations.